# Match hexadecimal string GAWK

Tags: regex, gawk

I want to match a 32 character hex string using gawk.

I've found that I can use /[A-F0-9]{32}/ , but only if I run gawk with --posix or --re

Is there any alternative without command line options? (aside from repeating [A-F0-9] 32 times!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
gawk '/^[A-F0-9]*$/ && length($0)==32'
```

Comment: ah that'll do it, thanks, I tried /[A-F0-9]*/  (I already know that my string is 32 chars)

Comment: /[A-F0-9]*/  (without ^ and $) is actually not safe. well it would be ok then, if you knew that your input is valid.